# Reading character by character to see if it is a digit

Tags: c++, string, character

I need help with this if statement. Im trying to read each character to see if it is a number. If it is not a digit then say it is not a number if it is continue reading on to the next character. for example if the user inputs 54gr 21 gr42 134 3f3. the only thing that would cout is 21 and 134.

```
#include <iostream> // libraries
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    char string[80];
    // char num[80];
    // char good[80];
    cout << "enter a string "; // prompting user 
    cin.getline(string,80); // geting line
    // int i = 0;
    // int j = 0;
    int count = 0;
    {

    while(string[count] != '\0') {

        if(string[count] >= '0' && string[count] <= '9' )
            cout << count << endl;
            }
           ++ count;
    }
    }
```

Comment: You're almost there. What's the question?

Comment: Numbers take many forms.  You don't handle decimal points or exponents. Is localization important?  If it this becomes more complicated.  Also, why use a char aray when you are in C++ land and can use a `std::string`?  I don't even know what the question is.  How about showing is input that *doesn't* work?

Answer (score 2):

I would not try to do this character by character. The problem is that you don't now that `5` is really part of a number until you've read to the end of the string of non-space characters to verify that *all* the contents are legitimately part of a number.

As such, I think you need/want to break the input up into "words", then check whether each complete word can be converted entirely to a number. You can read "words" with just `some_stream >> some_string;`

Once you have a "word" you check whether you can convert it entirely to a number. Assuming you want integers, you use `strtol` to (try to) convert it to a number. That will give you a pointer to the first character it couldn't convert as a number. If that's not the end of the string, then that "word" wasn't a number (even if it started with/contained one or more digits).